# How to create an infinite loop in Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, infinite-loop

This is basically what I want in a batch file. I want to be able to re-run "Do Stuff" whenever I press any key to go past the "Pause".

```
while(true){
    Do Stuff
    Pause
}
```

Looks like there are only `for` loops available and no `while` loops in batch. How do I create an infinite loop then?

Comment: Are you asking about a Windows/DOS batch file?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being vague, I'll make an addendum to the OP.

Comment: +1 ooops, I posted without noticing the other answer!

Comment: You can Use `For Command` Or [Link](http://www.trytoprogram.com/batch-file-for-loop/)

Answer (score 347, accepted):

How about using good(?) old [`goto`](http://www.computerhope.com/goto.htm)?

```
:loop

echo Ooops

goto loop
```

See also [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001050.htm) for a more useful example.

Comment: no good :D sometimes quicker but never good :D ok there is only one good place for goto - in the lowest programming x)

Comment: I agree with jave.web you should use the for loop suggestion below. You should almost never use goto in your code even it is scripting. Goto was cool back in GW Basic days in 80s.

Comment: I disagree with jave.web - there's nothing wrong with goto if you use it correctly. For example, I'm about to use it to ensure the program that is run within the loop auto-respawns if it dies for whatever reason. It may however be wise to put a small wait in the loop to stop cpu thrashing if my program dies instantly for some reason.

Comment: @theonlygusti **Doesn't work** as a one-line command, as you'd expect `:lbl & echo Ooops & goto lbl` ; **but @Nicholi 's comment below does**: `FOR /L (1,0,2) DO @echo Oops`

Comment: @JimB your command has `(1 was unexpected at this time.` error, I thinks this is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8846529/1407491

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. My mistake!  Multiple typos, should be `FOR /L %N IN (1,0,2) DO ECHO %N`. [Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file/5487520?noredirect=1#comment15033411_5488111) was right. In a batch file, it needs `FOR \L %%N `.  I like this one for its simplicity.

Comment: I think the reason goto is not recommended is it could make code unreadable. This example of shows how to use goto correctly, and is simple, super clear, and straightforward to understand. Other answers using for require knowing the syntax of for in windows batch.

Answer (score 140):

Unlimited loop in **one-line command** for use in `cmd` windows:

```
FOR /L %N IN () DO @echo Oops
```

[image]

Comment: To use that in a batch file type:
FOR /L %%N IN () DO @echo Oops

Comment: Just watch out for running commands which immediately exit, which is much more frequent on Windows than on Linux :-D

Answer (score 74):

A really infinite loop, counting from 1 to 10 with increment of 0.
You need infinite or more increments to reach the 10.

```
for /L %%n in (1,0,10) do (
  echo do stuff
  rem ** can't be leaved with a goto (hangs)
  rem ** can't be stopped with exit /b (hangs)
  rem ** can be stopped with exit
  rem ** can be stopped with a syntax error
  call :stop
)

:stop
call :__stop 2>nul

:__stop
() creates a syntax error, quits the batch
```

This could be useful if you need a really infinite loop, as it is much faster than a `goto :loop` version because a for-loop is cached completely once at startup.

Comment: Nice because it also works just typing it in at command prompt. for /L %n in (1,0,2) do @echo."hi guys"

Comment: Wish this solution had a little more explanation.

Answer (score 23):

read `help GOTO`

and try

```
:again
do it
goto again
```

Answer (score 7):

Another better way of doing it:

```
:LOOP
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK 
::pause or sleep x seconds also valid
call myLabel
if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :LOOP
```

This way you can take care of errors too

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the loop:

```
echo off
cls

:begin

set /P M=Input text to encode md5, press ENTER to exit: 
if %M%==%M1% goto end

echo.|set /p ="%M%" | openssl md5

set M1=%M%
Goto begin
```

This is the simple batch i use when i need to encrypt any message into md5 hash on Windows(openssl required), and the program would loyally repeat itself except given Ctrl+C or empty input.