# How to execute same windows command after regular intervals?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

i want to execute `wecutil rs` command after each 2 min interval on single machine. which is the best way to this ?
please provide example or link.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a batch file which contains FOR loop which contains your command call and SLEEP.

Comment: Thank you.Will you provide code of that for loop and sleep,because i dont know how to write batch file.

Comment: This is how to create an infinite loop (not FOR): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file. To sleep 2 minutes you need `sleep 120`.

Comment: when i try with sleep 120, it shows error "sleep is not recognized as internal or external command"