# How to stop socat from quitting?

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, dns, socat

I am using `socat` for windows as a client to tunnel DNS over SSH, it works perfectly until the `ssh` connection dies or becomes temporarily unavailable - when this happens the `socat` windows client terminates and requires restarting.

I am using the following command on windows client:

```
socat -s udp-recvfrom:53,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:5377
```

Does anyone know a way to prevent the socat client from quitting when the ssh connection becomes unavailable?  The help file suggests the `-s` switch solves this but it doesn't.

Comment: You could wrap the command with an [infinite loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file).

Comment: Not sure how to create an infinite loop - I'm running the command from a compiled vbscript with WshShell.Run "socat.exe -s udp-recvfrom:53,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:5377",0,false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment, a loop in VBScript (what Windows Scripting Host uses) is easier:

```vb
Do
    WshShell.Run "socat.exe -s udp-recvfrom:53,reuseaddr,bind=127.0.0.1,fork tcp:127.0.0.1:5377",0,True
Loop While True
```

Comment: this doesn't work, it just launches thousands of socat.exe processes

Comment: @Kyoku: Sorry, my bad.  Change the last `false` with `true` in the line you launch `socat`