# Looping Commands in Batch Scripts

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have the command:

```
:start
if /i "%%~fs"=="%drive%" cd %%~fs&md Favorites 2>nul
if /i "%%~fs"=="%drive%" cd %%~fs&md "Discography Info" 2>nul
...
goto start
```

How would I loop the command and each time put in a different name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it similar to this:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*) do call :printit "%%f"
goto :end
:printit arg1
echo %~1 ---- %1
exit /b 0
:end
echo Done.
pause
```

Comment: Can you loop the call :startx's as well? Or is that not possible?

Comment: This was actually very fun to try out and surprising in how user friendly it was, so thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not totally understanding your question.  I think there is enough information in my answer for you to figure out a infinite loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file