# Infinite loop Windows batch file?

Tags: loops, batch-file, infinite-loop

I have this bash script looped running in Linux, what is the Windows equivalent of doing this?

```
while ./process.sh; do sleep 1; done
```

I have a windows batch file that I would like to run as long as the return code is 0

Comment: There is another [very similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5487473/5047996) concerning infinite loops...

Comment: I tried to use the second answer and It didn't work for me.

Comment: What does not work? why? do you receive an error message, or what happens exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
cmd /q /e /c"for /l %%a in () do (call process.cmd || exit) & >nul timeout /t 1"
```

If you want to test it from command line, change `%%a` with `%a`

Comment: Me too! @MCND, why are you using `cmd /C`? I think it is not necessary, is it? just because of `/Q`??

Comment: @aschipfl, no, it is because I don't know if the process in the caller batch file needs to continue after this line. If I run the infinite `for /l` in batch context I can only use a `exit` to leave it, but the batch file will end. Starting the infinite loop in a separate `cmd` instance (that will run code in command line context) I can use `exit` or `exit /b` to leave the loop and keep running the caller batch file.

Comment: Aah, I see -- thanks a lot for your explanation! just note that `exit` **`/B`** **cannot** be used, it will **hang**...

Comment: @aschipfl, no, tested and it works as indicated. If the infinite `for /l` is running in command line context (the reason for the `cmd /c`, then the `exit /b` can force the loop to end. But, if the infinite `for /l` is executed in batch context (without the `cmd /c`) you can only leave it with an `exit`

Comment: Oops, I confused your explanation and my past opinion... yes, `exit /B` equals `exit` unless it is executed in a batch context... (I had in mind that `for` loops left by `goto` or `exit /B` continue iterating in the background until completion, but yes, `exit` will _always_ terminate it)

Comment: Wow, this is very nice. It uses less CPU than some of the others I found here, thanks!

Comment: excelent... I was searhin for a loop to use in command line and this one do the job quick'n'dirty !!! THX ~~~

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
:LOOP
timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
call "\path\to\your\process.sh\equivalent\batch\file"
if not ErrorLevel 1 goto :LOOP
```

**Note:** This does not work on the command line. You need to place this code in a batch file.

Comment: The `timeout` must be placed _before_ the `call`; otherwise the timeout modify the errorlevel returned by the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Aacini, i forgot about that... see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32339498/3)...