# Require user to enter correct code to continue

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch program. I want a verification system where you type the code, and it lets you continue. If you type the wrong code it won't let you continue.

Anyone got some code I can use for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: Can you give me the exact code please?

Comment: See `set /p`, `goto /?`, and `if /?`.

Comment: @Foetheorize no I can't?

Comment: They should really make people read all the howto articles on SO and give them a test before they are allowed to post questions.

Comment: I totally agree, @Squashman. New users should at least have the [Informed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge, so they have at least opended the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and scrolled to the bottom (this does still not prove whether they read *and* understood it though...).

Answer (score 0):

say if you wanted the password to be "1234" you would put:

```
@echo off
echo Enter the correct code:
set /p InputPass=Code: 
if '%InputPass%'=='1234' goto :AccessGranted
goto :AccessDenied

:AccessGranted
cls
echo Access Granted!
timeout 3 /nobreak >nul
goto :continue

:AccessDenied
cls
echo Access Denied!
echo Program on halt!
pause >nul
goto :AccessDenied

:continue
```

And then you would put in the code you want to execute if the user got it right, under the last line (which says :continue)