# How to run a command in an infinite loop in command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

In windows command prompt, I run a command like this

```
program.exe all
```

and it prints out stuff as it runs, then ends. How can I basically do this?

```
while (1) {
    program.exe all
}
```

but in a way that I can still see it print out the stuff, and I can stop it by just doing ctrl+c.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an infinite loop in Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
:while
(
   program.exe all
   goto :while
)
```

which is equal to while(true).

Comment: is that a .bat file?

Comment: also doesn't echo off, surpress the text output from the program.exe?

Comment: Yes, it is a bat file. 
And echo off (which should be @echo off) just turns off the print of the commands from the batch file (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)